# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' | discord.js error

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot that sends random messages from a server's channel. I get this error:

```
/home/runner/BuzzingCyberBlogs/index.js:19
        var messages =[const channel = client.channels.cache.get(727195963625570326)
                       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
```

The code is below:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = 'r!' ;
const token = '' ;

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${bot.user.tag} successfully logged in` )
  bot.user.setActivity('stupid messages', ({type: "LISTENING"}))
})

bot.on('message', message => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trime().split(/+/);

  switch(args[0]) {
    case 'msg':
      msgmessage(message);

      function msgmessage(message) {
        var messages =[
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(727195963625570326)
const randomMsg = channel.messages.cache.random(1)
message.channel.send(`"${randomMsg.content}" -${message.author}, ${message.createdAt}`)];
        var msg = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length);

        message.channel.send(messages[msg]);
      }
      break;
  }
})

bot.login(token);
```

I am not sure what to do. I am sure I did not include a const and a function together but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: Your array syntax is incorrect. You can learn more about arrays at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not valid because you have `var messages =[` unclosed.
Try using the code below:

```js
function msgmessage(message) {
    const messages = ["test", "test2"]

    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(727195963625570326)
    const randomMsg = channel.messages.cache.random(1)
    message.channel.send(`"${randomMsg.content}" -${message.author}, ${message.createdAt}`)];

    const msg = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length);
    message.channel.send(messages[msg]);
}
```

Also usage of `var` in Javascript is deprecated, use `let` instead!